# Is it possible to filter content based on existing term id?

Tags: views, 8

How to filter content based on taxonomy term id 
I have created a view in which news article are showing based on taxonomy term

Is it possible to filter content based existing term id

Suppose in view when i am filtering content with term id 23,24 its giving me result.

But when i am filtering content with 23,24,25 ,where 25 is randomly assumed number its still filtering content on the basis of 23,24 term id

Can we restrict content to filter.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you please update with more details. Is your example node tagged with both 23 and 24? What does "randomly assumed number" mean? Do you expect no results if you filter "`23,24,25`". What happens when you filter "`23+24+25`"? What is your contextual filter configuration?

Comment: `ìs it possible to filter content based existing term id` are you trying to say based on the term id of the page being viewed?